# Check if there is 4 letters in a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Alright, hello. I'm attempting to find the amount of letters in a message. If there are four letters, then it'll do the code I wrote down. The letters aren't certain, the only 2 letters that are certain are at the start and end which I already have down.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("H")) {
        if(message.content.endsWith("k")) {
            if(message.content.length == 4) { // This right here is the code I believe isn't working. It's supposed to check if there is 4 letters in the message. 
                message.delete();
                message.reply('Okay');
                message.member.roles.add("805088740737417256");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Though it doesn't detect if there is 4 letters. It still works if there is 3 letters, or more. Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the regex pattern `^H[A-Za-z]{2}k$`:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (/^H[A-Za-z]{2}k$/.test(message.content)) {
        message.delete();
        message.reply('Okay');
        message.member.roles.add("805088740737417256");
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining it to me? You don't have to.

Comment: The regex pattern literally just says to match any 4 character input starting with `H`, followed by any 2 letters, ending in `k`.